# Can you explain why my CPU usage is NOT as high as I'd expect in multi-threaded app?

Tags: .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task

I'm finding myself using the following pattern and I'd like some feedback. I have a .net console application that's producing millions of items (that get separated into hundreds of million items) so I've created the following (simplified) type to consume the items.

```
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly ChannelWriter<Item> writer;
    private readonly ChannelReader<Item> reader;
    private readonly Task task;

    public Consumer()
    {
        var unboundedChannel = Channel
            .CreateUnbounded<Item>(new UnboundedChannelOptions
            {
                AllowSynchronousContinuations = false,
                SingleReader = true,
                SingleWriter = true
            });
        this.writer = unboundedChannel.Writer;
        this.reader = unboundedChannel.Reader;
        this.task = Task
            .Factory
            .StartNew(async () => await this.consumer(), default, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default)
            .Unwrap();
    }

    public void Add(Item item)
    {
        if (!this.writer.TryWrite(item)) throw new Exception("Couldn't write to the channel for some reason.");
    }

    public void CompleteAdding()
    {
        this.writer.Complete();
    }

    public async Task WaitTillComplete()
    {
        await this.task;
    }

    private async Task consumer()
    {
        await Parallel.ForEachAsync
        (
            this.reader.ReadAllAsync(),
            new ParallelOptions { TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.Default },
            async (item, _) =>
            {
                // work is done here.
            }
        );
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my current thoughts / concerns

- I'm not getting the CPU usage I was hoping for. It usually hovers around 25% to 30%.
- Are there any inherit problems with Parallel.ForEachAsync reading directly from the reader.ReadAllAsync()?
- I currently have about 20 consumer instances that are very similar to this Consumer. Am I risking over saturating Tasks here? Is that even a thing?
- In testing my code, I added a await Task.Delay(25) within the "// work is done here" section (with no other code) to 1 of the Consumers. Thinking that each Consumer is running independent of each other, I would not have expected this addition of code to impact the other consumers. But instead I observed the other consumers not process as fast.

At this point I think I should probably profile my code but I thought I'd ask here to see if there was anything obviously wrong first.

Comment: Take a read of https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html It's possible you are simply bottlenecked on IO, the CPU is simply processing the data faster than it can be read off the disk/network/whatever

Comment: @Charlieface The more I think about this, the more I'm starting to understand what you are saying here and I think you are probably correct. I'm thinking that there's a bottleneck with memory IO. Thank you for the thought.